# git - update to new branch of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I currently have a rails project running of a git tag v2.1.2, to get here id did

```
git checkout v2.1.2
```

However there are now new fix's that have been applied to the 2.1 branch, how do I move to this branch rather than the tag?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a tag and a branch named the same. Then, to checkout to the branch, you would provide the path to it.

For example:

```
git checkout refs/heads/2.1
```

This disambiguates `2.1` branch from a tag named `2.1` itself.

Comment: Hi, sorry didn’t explain it properly, the branch I want to checkout is located at http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/2-1-stable

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new branch that tracks the remote 2-1-stable like so:

```
git checkout -b 2-1-stable origin/2-1-stable
```

Then just cd back to rails root and commit the submodule change.

Later if you need to update it, you should just be able to cd back into vendor/rails and:

```
git remote update
git rebase origin/2-1-stable
```

And commit the changes again.